# Adding a menu bar in constructor function

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

i am trying to add menu bar in addition to some functional Buttons, but i still have some errors each time i try to add menu bar code, what should be the code to be added in order me to have menubar here?

sorry for adding big chunck of code

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2

class GUI(tk.Frame):
    img = None
    img_is_found = False

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.grid(sticky=N + S + E + W)

        # Browse button
        self.file = Button(self, text='Browse', command=self.choose,
                           bg="#20bebe", fg="white", height=2, width=15)   

        #displayed image in label
        self.label = Label(image=None, width=900, height=600)


        ***#Menubar- this is the piece of code that causes the error**
        menubar = MenuBar(self)
        self.config(menu=menubar)
        fileMenu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=False)
        self.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Copy", underline=1, command=app.copy_stuff)


        self.pack()
        self.label.pack()
        self.file.pack()

    def choose(self):
       pass



root = Tk()
root.title('image ToolBox')

gui = GUI(root)
gui.mainloop()
```

#ERROR LOG

```
  File "/home/mma/PycharmProjects/img-proj/test.py", line 43, in __init__
    menubar = MenuBar(self)
NameError: name 'MenuBar' is not defined. Did you mean: 'menubar'?
```

###################

if i removed the menubar chunck of code,actually there was no errors occurred :)

[the ui when running the code without the menubar piece of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aos30.png)

Comment: Where do you think `MenuBar` is coming from? It doesn't look like you're importing it from anywhere.

Comment: @BryanOakley kindly, can you suggest the right way for importing it ?

Comment: No, I can't, because I don't know what it is. Tkinter doesn't have a `MenuBar` widget, so I don't know what widget you're trying to use.

Comment: When asking questions here, you should supply a [mre] with *just enough* code in it to illustrate the problem — not all of the code in your program with all kinds of unrelated stuff in it.

Comment: @martineau , ok,  the question edited with enough code, sorry for disturb, but this is the first time to ask a question here,

Comment: That's more like it — although the `PIL` and `cv2` imports are unnecessary. You're still referring to something named a `MenuBar` which is not a standard `tkinter` widget. There *are* ways of creating them (if they're what I think they are) with `tkinter`, but I can only guess. What made you think there was such a thing?

Comment: usually tutorials such as [this one (see the example section at the end)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_menu.htm) use a variable named `menubar` but they all usually use the `Menu` widget anyways

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that you don't really have a `MenuBar` class from anywhere, and instead mistakenly think it's coming from tkinter. Tkinter doesn't have a `MenuBar` widget, but it does have a `Menu` widget from which you can create a menubar.

The next mistake you're making is in trying to attach the menu to a frame. Frames don't have a `menu` option, only the root window and `Toplevel` widgets do.

Another mistake is trying to call `add_cascade` on `self`. That is a method on a menu, not on your custom class.

And finally, unless there is a very compelling reason to do so (and there rarely is), the menus should be children of the menu they are being added to.

You need to change your code to look something like this:

```
menubar = Menu(master)
master.config(menu=menubar)

fileMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=fileMenu)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Copy", underline=1, command=app.copy_stuff)
```